# Does Google get a list of APK packages installed outside of Google Play?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, apk, privacy

I use Gmail on my Android 11 phone, not only for email but also for some other services of Google such as Maps). Due to privacy concerns, I've been thinking about installing some applications (such as Bitcoin wallets or encrypted messengers) that are offered by the Google Play Store directly from an APK package (I mean without any other store such as F-Droid, hoping that no information of the fact that such package is installed is sent to Google).

Is such information sent anyway? If it is, what other information is sent to Google about those applications (usage?)?

Comment: As we already had questions about Google Play Store updating app installed by other stores you can assume that Google knows all the apps installed on your device.

Comment: If you have a Google account on your device, Google likely knows EVERYTHING you do on your device. And yes, they can see what other apps you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing an application through other means apart from the Play Store. If the app matches the version in the Play Store, the Play Store will recognize it as installed (you can then even update over the existing app using the Play Store). Even if you go to the store on a seperate device, it will recognize it as installed on the first device.

If you don't trust the Play Store, then you should try to remove it entirely.